# convert vuetify markup to html

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I need to reuse some of my vuetify layout in an app that does not use vuetify.
Is it possible to convert vuetify html components to their underlying html markup?
I don't care about the css

Answer (score 3):

You technically could, however, you would lose all of the functionality associated with them. If that's not an issue, you could simply create your layout and copy the markup from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still using `Vue.js` in your app? If so the easiest thing would definitely be to add vuetify into the project. If you add in the `<script>` and `<link>` for vuetify BEFORE your other dependencies. Your other dependencies should overwrite any styling etc that your dependencies use.

If you remove the vuetify css (as you stated you don't care about) the layout for the app becomes completely broken therefore it is a necessity You are best to try and rebuild the app structure using another framework or include vuetify for the one component you need.

Try running this, then remove the cdn for the CSS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-navigation-drawer
      fixed
      v-model="drawer"
      app
    >
      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-tile @click="">
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>home</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>Home</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile @click="">
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>contact_mail</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>Contact</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-toolbar color="indigo" dark fixed app>
      <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Application</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-toolbar>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid fill-height>
        <v-layout
          justify-center
          align-center
        >
          <v-flex text-xs-center>
            <v-tooltip left>
              <v-btn icon large :href="source" target="_blank" slot="activator">
                <v-icon large>code</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
              <span>Source</span>
            </v-tooltip>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
    <v-footer color="indigo" app inset>
      <span class="white--text">&copy; 2017</span>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</div>
 
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: () => ({
        drawer: null
      })
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```